# A leader of a movement?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone who has come to represent or be a symbol of some ideology, someone who others follow and have deified, but who is still alive.

Preferably with religious connotations.

> Tyler Durden, in pop culture, has come to be a _______

Noun

---

This question was previously phrased as asking for a word that would describe a living martyr - someone who has come to be iconic and represent a particular cultural movement.

Comment: Representing some ideology has nothing to do with martyrdom...

Comment: @curiousdannii you are right, but idk the word I need.

Comment: Then describe more what you mean.

Comment: @curiousdannii - ***martyr*** - a person who suffers very much or is killed because of  ***their religious or political beliefs***, and is often admired because of it. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/martyr

Comment: @theonlygusti - you question is clear and correct.

Comment: @JOSH yes but a martyr doesn't necessarily become an iconic representative of their ideology - most die and are forgotten.

Comment: @curiousdannii - OP is asking what they are called when the become iconic...Mandela, Gandhi etc.....but as usual the only thing you are able to do is closevoting and downvoting.

Comment: @Josh Yes but for someone who hasn't died or maybe even suffered! If only 0.1% of martyrs became iconic representives, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to ask what you should call an iconic martyr who never suffered... That would be mixing up the essential characteristic with a rare secondary characteristic. But the OP has edited the question so it doesn't matter any more.

Comment: Aren't you describing a *leader*?  And don't various movements tend to pick their own terms for such leaders, such as "shaman", "priest", "elder", "lama", "counselor", etc?

Comment: What @HotLicks said, you need to specify what religion you are referring to. Also, you need to explain why "(living) (religions) iconic leader" would not be the phrase you are looking for.

Comment: This question was closed (rightfully, IMO) for not indicating how the desired word would be used. I consider a specification of the part of speech to be an essential element of a swr question. Do you want a noun or an adjective? If an adjective, what’s wrong with “iconic” (which you used in the question)?

Comment: It's still incredibly unclear:  How is "leader" not a sufficient term?  What connotation is sought?  Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?  Do you want a "sensible" term or a mystical one?  **What is it you want???**

Answer (score 7):

The word that you are looking for may be [***icon***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/icon):

> **Icon** noun [ C ]
>
> - ​A very famous person or thing considered as representing a set of
>   beliefs or a way of life:
> - *Beckham has been one of the country's best-loved sporting icons.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I think you may use the expression ***[living legend](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/living-legend):***

> - someone who is extremely famous during the time that they are alive.

(Macmillan Dictionary)

- ***[Mohandas Gandhi:](http://blogs.iac.gatech.edu/unreliable/2013/10/07/mohandas-gandhi-the-living-legend-of-his-time/)*** ***The Living Legend of His Time***
- ***[Mandela: The living legend](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p00w7kkh)***

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I like it. It doesn't have the religious connotations I need, but it isn't a bad answer imo.

Comment: I find it to be a perfectly apt answer. +1.

Comment: Good answer.  You could also take the name of a living religious leader.  I'm not really up on religious leaders, so I can't think of one offhand, but if we pretend that Mother Theresa were alive now, maybe you could say, "Tyler Durden has come to be a [or *the*] Mother Theresa of pop culture."  I'm not sure, because I never heard of Tyler Durden and I'm not very well up on pop culture *or* religion.

Answer (score 2):

One could appropriate the religious word *messiah,* not giving it a capital letter.

It's obviously derived from *the Messiah* (capital M), but has become genericised:

> A leader regarded as the saviour of a particular country, group, or cause:
>   *‘the club's supporters have been tempted to regard him as a messiah rather than a manager’*
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/messiah)]

OED has a similar definition, following **1** which is the capital-letter proper noun:

> **2.** In extended use (now usu. in form **messiah**): an actual or expected liberator or saviour of an oppressed people, country, etc.; a zealous leader of any cause or enterprise.

Their first citation for this use was by Dryden in 1667, where he used a capital letter as was customary at the time for many nouns.

> 1667   Dryden *Annus Mirabilis 1666* cxiv. 29   The wily Dutch, who, like fall'n Angels, fear'd This new Messiah's coming.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

> - savior (with a lower-case "S")
> - standard bearer
> - hero
> - champion
> - liberator
> - idol
> - role model
> - an embodiment of ___________ (fill in the blank)
> - the epitome of ____________ (fill in the blank)
> - *beau idéal*
> - apotheosis
> - exemplar
> - a paradigm, as in "a paradigm of virtue"
> - a god (obviously with a lower-case "G")
> - revered (obviously an adjective)
> - venerated (another adjective)
> - saint

Answer (score 0):

I'd say: [spiritual leader](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spiritual+leader).

It may seem the figure is powerless politically, however, in some religions the spiritual leader holds the actual power. Example could be: Catholic Pope throughout the middle ages or Muslim leaders nowadays.